# Facebook Page to Page Messaging Not Sent To API

Tags: facebook, integration, messenger

We have a messaging Application which is integrated into Facebook Messenger through the Messenger API.  It works very well and have been working very well for about two years.  Recently our customers informed us that if one of their customers message them using using Page-to-page messaging then the message does not appear in our app.

We investigated this and it seems that when a user messages while being on a Page Profile then the message goes directly into the Inbox and never gets sent to the Messenger API.  More and more people are messaging using pages which in effect has made our application half-baked for our customer.

Only 20% of the inbound messages are coming from Facebook and about 2% have this issue.  So with these conversations the customer now needs to switch into Facebook and answer through Facebook which totally breaks their workflow.  This is a large organization with about fifteen incoming facebook pages. I will appreciate any insight into this issue - thank you.

We analyzed incoming traffic to the API and can confirm that these conversations are not coming into our integration.  We then created a test Facebook App for the integration and enabled all security rights but still nothing.